# Allowing master tag instead of the synonym tag in the jobs creation

Tags: feature-request, stack-overflow-jobs, tag-synonym-process

Today I see a job post in the side bar with the [ms-sql-server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ms-sql-server) tag.

> [image: Job in side bar]

Actually [ms-sql-server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ms-sql-server) is [remapped](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/sql-server/synonyms) to [sql-server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sql-server) and every where in Stack Overflow  it is referred as [sql-server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sql-server) only. But showing [ms-sql-server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ms-sql-server) in job's tag is inconsistency.

So my [feature-request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/feature-request) is instead of allowing the synonym tag, kindly allow the master tags only in the creation of jobs.

**Example:** While posting a question, in the **Tags** section if I type a synonym tag it automatically showing the master tag only, in that way.

> [image: Tags in Question]

Comment: I have the strangest feeling I've seen a very similar post before but it was a bug report that I think was by design... umm... or I could be imagining it...

Comment: Meh, it's called MS SQL Server