# 'angular2' tag did not update to 'angular'

Tags: feature-request, stack-overflow-jobs, tag-synonym-process, profile-page

[Earlier](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/339879/what-to-do-about-angular-2) this year, Stack Overflow changed all of the `[angular2]` tags to `[angular]`.

I just went into my *Users* → *Edit Profile & Settings* → *Job Preferences* → *Technologies* to update my job search status and found that the `[angular2]` tag was still there (unchanged) even though this tag no longer exists on the rest of the site.

Comment: Related: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/327951/allowing-master-tag-instead-of-the-synonym-tag-in-the-jobs-creation

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Good catch.

Currently, there is no mechanism to retag "liked tags". That is, when tag synonyms on Stack Overflow are updated, the existing liked tags in job preferences stay unchanged.

However, the tag editor autocomplete (which pops up when you edit the liked tags field) features *up-to-date* canonical tags. Since [angular2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angular2) is currently a synonym of the canonical tag [angular](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angular),
 [angular2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angular2) won't appear in the tag editor autocomplete, but [angular](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angular) will. Also note that you can put *whatever your like* as a tag in your liked tags. The autocomplete is just guidance, not a rule. Go ahead and add [bananas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bananas) if you wish.

Additionally, the liked tags of candidates who [expressed interest in being contacted by employers](https://stackoverflow.com/users/jobsearch/current#status) are displayed "as-in" in [candidate search](https://www.stackoverflowbusiness.com/talent/platform/source/candidate-search).

Finally, tag synonyms are applied in our job search and job recommendations algorithms. That means that if you have [angular2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angular2) in your liked tags, both [angular](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angular) and [angular2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angular2) jobs will be surfaced in search results / recommendations.

Now, for my opinion on this.

There can be an argument about whether or not *systematically retagging all liked tags when tag synonyms are changed* would be a good idea. A benefit of *not* retagging liked tags is that the initial intent of the user is not compromised.

Recruiters tend to be unfamiliar with the SO tag synonyms system, so it's probably desirable to make things as simple as possible for them. In other words, in your specific example, [angular2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angular2) is less ambiguous to a neophyte than [angular](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angular): replacing all instances of [angular2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angular2) to [angular](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angular)  might increase ambiguity.

All that being said, I'll bring your concern to the team.

Comment: You make some very valid points. I just don't want to see people missing out on potential job opportunities when an employer seraches for someone with "angular" skills and then the people with the deprecated tag get missed out (likewise for other synonyms). If this isn't going to happen, then I think leaving "as is", is also acceptable. A side note, It's really odd you can whack in what ever you want into those tech tags but I suppose if SO doesn't have an instance of a desired tag then it makes sense.

Comment: @Zze Re: candidate search. Tag synonyms are also applied there. A search for "angular" returns exactly the same profiles as a search for "angular2"